# How do I access the Network tab/object (and its properties) shown as a tab in browser development tools?

Tags: javascript, browser, console.log, devtools

[image: A Network tab in Chrome Dev Tools]
How do I access the "Network" tab underlined in the image above, and its properties, in a "index.js" code file.

For instance, I could access the "Console" tab and its properties in the Chrome Dev Tools using the `console` object. Eg:

```
console.log()
// Or
console.info()
```

So the real question is, can I access the Dev Tools' "Network" tab and its properties, and even other tabs like "Element", or "Source", etc, in a "index.js" code file?

I could only carry out some certain tasks in Dev Tools itself, but can't access it to carry out tasks in a "index.js" code file.

Comment: What do you mean by "access the tab"?  You can output data to the console, yes.  Do you want to... output network request information to the network tab?  Then you'd do that by... making a network request.  Are you just looking for the term "AJAX" for your code?

Comment: You can't. And since that is too short for an answer I'm leaving it as a comment

Comment: @David, not output, but access.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is no, the network tab is only used to see the HTTP requests and get info about them and some other things for testing, you cannot get the properties of the network tab in your code and also there aren't any features that you would want from it in your code, and apart from that many of the things which you are looking for can be achieved with node js and some npm packages.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Sadly I don't have enough "juice" to upvote your answer.

Comment: I do want to ask though, how do I achieve my goal of automating tasks? Tasks that depends on http requests? Do I need to learn nodejs? What npm packages can I install for that?

Comment: Yes, learning node.js is a must if you want to interact and use HTTP requests. Now coming to npm packages you should first learn node if you haven't, you will find many of your answers there.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Spa4k. I apologize for the late response.